# What do these SharePoint Services do?

Tags: 2007, administration, timer-service

I stopped the SharePoint services below which were running on the SharePoint 2007 Server (Single server mode) however all the web-applications are still accessible and I am able to perform administration tasks from CA and stsadm is working perfectly. So what is the function of these services? And how do they work with the SharePoint Web-applications?

- Windows SharePoint Services
- Administration Windows SharePoint
- Services Search Windows SharePoint
- Services Timer Windows SharePoint
- Services Tracing Windows SharePoint
- Services VSS Writer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never disable the Timer and Administration Service.

From [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288765.aspx):

> To facilitate this centralized
>   configuration model, Windows
>   SharePoint Services 3.0 relies on two
>   new and enhanced services: the Windows
>   SharePoint Services Administration
>   service and the Windows SharePoint
>   Services Timer service. The Windows
>   SharePoint Services Timer service acts
>   as the heartbeat for the server farm
>   and is responsible for running timer
>   jobs that propagate configuration
>   settings across a server farm. The
>   Windows SharePoint Services
>   Administration service works hand in
>   hand with the Windows SharePoint
>   Services Timer service and is
>   responsible for carrying out the
>   actual configuration changes on each
>   of the servers in your server farm.

The Tracing Service writes to the ULS trace Log. If you want to reduce tracing then do so via central administration (Central Admin / Operations / Diagnostic Logging), don't disable the service.

VSS Writer is used by certain backup applications, you may not need it if you are not backing up your SharePoint environment.

The Search Service is used for Search Indexing. You probably don't want to stop this service, even when you are running another Search Indexer in parallel as it is used for indexing the built-in help.